How to execute code when clicking on button in properties panel (Blender add-on Python)?
Blender 3d 2.90.1,
Python 3.10,
bpy
Hello, I am working on an add-on to automate the process of creating sprites that I assemble in the form of spritesheets. My code worked so far but as soon as I want to execute it after a button is clicked the code does not work anymore. It's a add-on for Blender 2.90.1. I created a panel with a button. My add-on is coded in Python.
Here is my code :
    "name " : "Sprite 3D",
    "blender": (2, 90, 1),
    "category": "Object",
    }

import bpy

def main(context):
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
    # j'ajoute une lumière
    bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SUN', align='WORLD', location=(18.332, 31.9635, 1.49041), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-18.3947, -31.6955, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.context.object.data.energy = 1000
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.160171, 3.23363, 7.385), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.160171, 3.23363, 7.385), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # j'ajoute  un denoiser
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.use_denoising = True
    # je rends le fond  transparent
    bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True
    # je créé une curve cerlce
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(9.95, 9.95, 9.95), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # je créé un deuxième cercle
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(3.26543, 3.26543, 3.26543), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, -9.88833, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # un troisième cercle que je duplique plusieurs fois que je déplace
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-9.87506, 9.9547, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(19.7501, -0.0796376, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-9.87506, 9.9547, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-9.87506, 9.9547, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":True, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.229356, -7.70401e-07, 5.73391), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(10.5687, -19.8164, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(3.12577, 3.12577, 3.12577), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1.30785, 1.30785, 1.30785), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # j'ajoute une camera que je déplace 
    bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(17.0456, -7.07043, 0), rotation=(0, -0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-16.8577, -6.07794, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.16833, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='VIEW', orient_matrix=((4.93038e-32, 1, 2.22045e-16), (2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32, 1), (1, 2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32)), orient_matrix_type='VIEW', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.16833, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='VIEW', orient_matrix=((4.93038e-32, 1, 2.22045e-16), (2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32, 1), (1, 2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32)), orient_matrix_type='VIEW', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(1.24772e-15, 0.688069, 5.61923), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(1.24772e-15, 0.688069, 5.61923), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # je mets la camera en mode isométrique
    bpy.context.object.data.type = 'ORTHO'
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.17858, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='VIEW', orient_matrix=((4.93038e-32, 1, 2.22045e-16), (2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32, 1), (1, 2.22045e-16, 4.93038e-32)), orient_matrix_type='VIEW', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # je change la taille de l'image
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 250
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 250
    # je sélectionne la camera
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='CAMERA')
    # je déplace la caméra
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.0607051, -3.01782e-07, 2.24609), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-7.7256e-16, -2.33017, -5.32167), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    # je sélectionne mon cercle
    objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects["BezierCircle.005"]
    objectToSelect.select_set(True) 
    # je sélectionne ma caméra
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
    bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=False)
    objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
    objectToSelect.select_set(True) 
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(11.7757, 11.7757, 11.7757), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.context.object.cycles.is_shadow_catcher = True
        
class ObjectSprite3D(bpy.types.Operator):
            """"My Sprite 3d setting Script"""
            bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
            bl_label = "Sprite3D"
            bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
        
def execute(self, context): 
    main(context)
    return{'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectSprite3D.bl_idname)
    




class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        scene = context.scene

        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Big Button:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 3.0
        row.operator("object.simple_operator")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectSprite3D)
    #bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectSprite3D)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    register()
    


i can only see that the indentations of def execute and menu_func is worng. this should actually throw an error, because whats self then?

Hello, I changed the identation of def execute and menu_func but only the light is created when I click on the button

I worked ! Thank you
